# Ассемблер. Замена определенного символа в файле

Tags: ассемблер

Добрый день. Необходимо реализовать программу на ассемблере, выполняющую:
1. Создание файла с именем XXXXXXXX.LAB, где XXXXXXXX - Ваша фамилия.
2. Запись в файл строки: - фамилия, имя, номер группа.
3. Чтение файла и вывода содержимого на экран.
4. Изменение атрибутов файла - сделать его скрытым.
5. Запись в режиме прямой адресации в файл на место элемента 5  цифры  8.
6. Чтение из файла элементов с номерами  3 - 10 и вывода их на  экран.

Пункты 1-4 выполнить получилось, но никак не получается выполнить последние 2 пункта. Ниже приведен код программы, который, на мой взгляд, должен выполнять пункты 1-5.

```
.model small

data segment
    cr      equ 0dh
    lf      equ 0ah
    string  db  'AndrewS-31',cr,lf      ;строка для записи
    strlnth equ $-string                ;ее длина
    handle  dw  ?                       ;ячейка для дескриптора
    fname   db  'Solodovnikov.LAB',0    ;имя файла в формате asciiz
    buffin  db  12 dup ('')             ;буфер ввода
    replace db  '8'
  replength equ $-replace
data ends
code segment
    assume cs:code, ds:data
main:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    ;создадние файла

    mov ah, 3ch                      ;функция создания файла
    mov cx, 0                        ;без аттрибутов
    mov dx, offset fname             ;адрес имени файла
    int 21h
    mov handle, ax                   ;сохраним дескриптор файла

    ;запись в файл строкиs

    mov ah, 40h                      ;функция записи
    mov bx, handle                   ;дескриптор
    mov cx, strlnth                  ;длина строки
    mov dx, offset string            ;адрес строки
    int 21h

    ;закрытие файла
    mov ah, 3eh                      ;функция закрытия
    mov bx, handle                   ;дескриптор
    int 21h

    ;открытие файла
    mov ah, 3dh
    mov al, 2h
    mov dx, offset fname
    int 21h
    mov handle, ax

    ;чтение из файла строки
    mov ah, 3fh
    mov bx, handle
    mov cx, strlnth
    mov dx, offset buffin
    int 21h


    ;вывод строки на консоль
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1h
    mov cx, 0ch
    mov dx, offset buffin
    int 21h

    ;изменение атрибута файла
    mov dx, offset fname
    mov cl, 2h
    mov al, 1h
    mov ah, 43h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 42h                      ;функция перемещения указателя
    mov al, 0                        ;выбор смещения: относительно начала файла
    mov cx, 0                        ;
    mov dx, 5h                       ;смещение на 5 позиций
    mov bx, handle
    int 21h

    mov ah, 40h                      ;функция записи
    mov bx, handle                   ;дескриптор
    mov cx, replength                ;длина строки
    mov dx, offset replace           ;адрес строки
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

code ends
end main
```

Но в результате, последних двух блоков кода будто бы и нет. Что нужно исправить, чтобы программа выполняла требуемое?

Comment: Т.е. атрибуты у файла меняются, а последняя запись не происходит ?

Comment: @Mike, да -- аттрибут файла меняется, а последняя запись не происходит. Сейчас попробую задать значение в регистре AL при открытии файла.

Comment: При добавлении строчки `mov al, 02h` в блоке открытия файла в хоте выполнения программы срабатывает исключение: "Процессор обнаружил недопустимую инструкцию".  
При этом, присваивание атрибута "скрытый" выполнилось, несмотря на то, что оно идет после задания значения в регистр AL. Т.е. исключение сработало в одном из двух изначально проблемных блоков.

Comment: Нет, строка не печатается. Ну и занятно то, что без добавления той строчки (mov al, 02h) исключение не происходит.

Comment: Я кажется понял. Если заменить в моей исходной программе `replength` и `replace` на `strlenth` и `string`, то строка печатается, причем именно с пятого символа. Т.е. проблема именно в строке `replace` или `replength` (правда, никак не пойму, какая).

Comment: `mov ah, 2ch`, `int 21h`  в конце, я правильно понял? Добавил, но программа так же валится.

Comment: 4c, а не 2c....

Comment: Так, занятно... теперь символ меняется, но не на "8", а на "А". Несмотря на то, что строкой указана replace, a не string.
Исключение не всплывает.

Comment: bufin на всякий случай сделайте побольше, байт 20 хотя бы. у меня ощущение, что переменная за ним затирается при чтении, правда я не понимаю каким образом.

Comment: Смена размера bufin на 20 не помогла. Но проблему я все же решил: в buffin начальное значение я сделал не пустую строку (''), а пробел (' '). В итоге, появилась восьмерка и причем там где нужно. Я правда все равно не до конца понимаю почему все так, но рад хотя быто тому, что все работает. Премного благодарен!

Comment: @АндрейСолодовников, рад что решение найдено, пожалуйста, оформите его ответом.

Comment: хм. оригинально. похоже, что он брал длину пустой строки и умножал на 12. в итоге буфер был нулевой длины (0*12). вы туда читали строку и как раз буква A оказывалась в replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением стало исправление нескольких проблем, ключевой из которых было то, что  значение replace переписывалось при чтении буфера (из-за его изначальной нулевой длины). Помимо прочего, был явно указан атрибут открытия файла (чтение-запись) и добавлена функция завершения программы.
Результирующий код выглядит следующим образом:

```
.model small

data segment
    cr      equ 0dh
    lf      equ 0ah
    string  db  'AndrewS-31',cr,lf      ;строка для записи
    strlnth equ $-string                ;ее длина
    handle  dw  ?                       ;ячейка для дескриптора
    fname   db  'Solodovnikov.LAB',0    ;имя файла в формате asciiz
    buffin  db  20 dup (' ')            ;буфер ввода
    replace db  '8'
  replength equ $-replace
data ends
code segment
    assume cs:code, ds:data
main:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    ;создадние файла

    mov ah, 3ch                      ;функция создания файла
    mov cx, 0                        ;без аттрибутов
    mov dx, offset fname             ;адрес имени файла
    int 21h
    mov handle, ax                   ;сохраним дескриптор файла

    ;запись в файл строкиs

    mov ah, 40h                      ;функция записи
    mov bx, handle                   ;дескриптор
    mov cx, strlnth                  ;длина строки
    mov dx, offset string            ;адрес строки
    int 21h

    ;закрытие файла
    mov ah, 3eh                      ;функция закрытия
    mov bx, handle                   ;дескриптор
    int 21h

    ;открытие файла
    mov ah, 3dh
    mov al, 2h
    mov dx, offset fname
    int 21h
    mov handle, ax

    ;чтение из файла строки
    mov ah, 3fh
    mov bx, handle
    mov cx, strlnth
    mov dx, offset buffin
    int 21h


    ;вывод строки на консоль
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1h
    mov cx, 0ch
    mov dx, offset buffin
    int 21h

    ;изменение атрибута файла
    mov dx, offset fname
    mov cl, 2h
    mov al, 1h
    mov ah, 43h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 42h                      ;функция перемещения указателя
    mov al, 0                        ;выбор смещения: относительно начала файла
    mov cx, 0                        ;
    mov dx, 4h                       ;смещение на 5 позиций
    mov bx, handle
    int 21h

    mov ah, 40h                      ;функция записи
    mov bx, handle                   ;дескриптор
    mov cx, 1h                       ;длина строки
    mov dx, offset replace           ;адрес строки
    int 21h

    mov ah, 42h                      ;функция перемещения указателя
    mov al, 0                        ;выбор смещения: относительно начала файла
    mov cx, 0                        ;
    mov dx, 2h                       ;смещение на 5 позиций
    mov bx, handle
    int 21h

    ;чтение из файла строки
    mov ah, 3fh
    mov bx, handle
    mov cx, 7h
    mov dx, offset buffin
    int 21h

    ;вывод строки на консоль
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1h
    mov cx, 7h
    mov dx, offset buffin
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

code ends
end main
```